# Delete checkbox containing row in form of html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-table, delete-row

```js
<script>
function delBoxes(){
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');
    var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');
    for(var i = 0; i<boxes.length; i++){
        box = boxes[i];
        txt = texts[i];
        if(box.checked){
            box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
            txt.parentNode.removeChild(txt);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>  

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<table border="1" id="table">  
   <tr>  <td colspan="2">Select Technolgy:</td>   </tr>  
   <tr>  <td>c</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="c" class='chk'></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  <td>hadoop</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="hadoop" class = 'chk'></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>   <td>core java</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="Core JAVA"  class='chk'></td>  
   </tr>  

<input type="button" value="Click" id="btntest" />
<input type="checkbox" class = 'chk' /> and
<input type="text" class = 'txt' />
<input type="button" value="Delete checked boxes" onclick = "delBoxes();" />
</form>


</body>  
</html>
```

Using this code, I candelete the checked checkbox. But how can I remove the checked checkbox containing row of table in the form?

I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650108/how-to-delete-a-check-box-using-javascript), but it didn't help me.

Comment: If i use for this delete jquery  library then load will increase for my server to load javascript and juery also to avoid that i am trying in javascript only

Answer (score 1):

Editing your code you can do it like this

```js
function delBoxes() {
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');
  var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    box = boxes[i];
    if (box.checked) {
      rowTag = box.parentNode.parentNode;
      tableTag = box.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
      tableTag.removeChild(rowTag);
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("deleteButton").addEventListener("click", delBoxes);
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <table border="1" id="table">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Select Technolgy:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="c" class='chk'>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hadoop</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="hadoop" class='chk'>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>core java</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="Core JAVA" class='chk'>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <input type="button" value="Click" id="btntest" />
    <input type="checkbox" class='chk' />and
    <input type="text" class='txt' />
    <input type="button" id="deleteButton" value="Delete checked boxes" />
</form>
```

But you have to consider changing design to something better. Set ids or classes and refer to them, instead of relative "magic number of levels".

If you mark rows with `data-tech` attribute then you could do something like:

```js
    function delBoxes() {
        var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("chk");
        for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
          box = classname[i]
          if (box.checked) {
            elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tech="' + box.value + '"]');
            elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
          }
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("deleteButton").addEventListener("click", delBoxes);
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <table border="1" id="table">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Select Technolgy:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tech="c">
      <td>c</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="c" class='chk'>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tech="hadoop">
      <td>hadoop</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="hadoop" class='chk'>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tech="Core JAVA">
      <td>core java</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="Core JAVA" class='chk'>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <input type="button" value="Click" id="btntest" />
    <input type="checkbox" class='chk' /> and
    <input type="text" class='txt' />
    <input type="button" id="deleteButton" value="Delete checked boxes" />
</form>
```

Comment: can you once explain how the below lines working in the $checkbox1=$_POST['techno'];  
$chk="";  
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
   {  
      $chk .= $chk1."";  
    echo '<script>alert("Inserted Successfully")</script>';
   }

Comment: can you visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035870/can-i-able-to-write-with-out-issetpost-for-the-below-code

Comment: provided code stores selected value (one value or array) into `$checkbox1` and then iterate through that array and write "alert" as much times as you had elements. Generally I am not happy that server side script writes inline javascript and alert something.